# SailsJS Include node_module in view

Tags: npm, gruntjs, sails.js, vuejs2

I'm using sails(http://sailsjs.com) to develop a little platform. Everything goes smoothly following the documentation. But being new to this javascript frameworks world and npm etc etc, i've been having a trouble including other node_modules and use them in the .ejs views...
I understand not all modules are to be included in the views but how can I manage to include some?
Trying to use https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-slider-component
Thank you in advance and sorry if this error is just plain out stupid.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your confusion is understandable.  The issue is that, until relatively recently, things installed in `node_modules` were solely for use in the *back end* code; that is, your Sails.js controller actions, models, etc.  After all, the `node_modules` folder has the word "Node" right in it, and it was created for use with NPM (the *Node* Package Manager) to help organize *Node* (i.e. *server-side* JavaScript) files!

While many front-end plugins were (and still are) published on [Bower](https://bower.io/), newer frameworks like Angular 2 and Vue often publish their plugins to NPM because it reduces the number of moving parts for your app.  The problem is, if you try to `require('vue-slider-component')` in your server-rendered `.ejs` view, the *server* (i.e. Sails.js) will try and load and run that code before it renders the view, where what you really want is for that plugin to run *in the browser*.

The long-term solution is to use something like [Browserify](http://browserify.org) or [Webpack](https://webpack.js.org/) to compile all of your front-end JavaScript files into a "bundle".  So for example if you have a file like `assets/js/my-vue-app.js` that includes the line:

```
import vueSlider from 'vue-slider-component/src/vue2-slider.vue'
```

then Browserify will see that line, load up that `vue2-slider.vue` file, add it to the top of the `my-vue-app.js` file, perform some other magic, combine it with your other front-end .js files and output a file like `browserified.js` which you would then include via `<script src="/path/to/browserified.js">` in your HTML.

Since new Sails apps use Grunt to organize and inject those `<script>` tags into your views for you, it can be kinda confusing as to how you would get something like Browserify or Webpack to work with Sails.  For Sails 1.0, there's a [seed project](https://github.com/sailshq/sails-webpack-seed) for using Webpack instead of Grunt.  For Sails v0.12.x, you'll have to Google around to find some examples of using Broswerify or Webpack with Sails.

A short-term solution, and probably not as maintainable in the long run, is to save the contents of the [minified vue-js-slider component](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/NightCatSama/vue-slider-component/master/dist/index.js) into your assets folder (e.g. as `assets/js/vue-slider-component.js`), add it to your HTML with `<script src="/js/vue-slider-component.js">` and access it in your code as `window['vue-slider-component']`.

Comment: Thanks for this amazing explanation. I've managed to use webpack, creating a bundle.js on the root project and then use webpack to compile it into assets whenever I use sails lift. That way I can require stuff into the browser. Including vue plugins and such. It is a shame I can only upvote once.