# Node Package not accessible in Sails.js

Tags: node.js, sails.js, node-modules

I installed node package via npm install and the Data is located in the node_modules directory as own directory.

But if re-lift and afterwards access a function of this new module, the browser told me, function not defined.

Do I need to add the path of the .js file in the layout or anywhere else?

Comment: There's not enough information here to help.

Comment: What information can I give to you? 
I am using a sails.js environment and installed in the project node_modules the package sweetalert2. 
However, if I am using it in the "beforeMount" area, it does not open :/

Comment: If I am using CDN: <script src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/sweetalert2@11"></script>
It works. Do I need to include it via src="/node_modules/package_name.js" ?

Comment: Depends on how SailsJS currently packages client-side code. It used to use Grunt for front-end assets, I know people have used Webpack, e.g., https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43186624/sailsjs-include-node-module-in-view.